# Error after updating meteor to 0.9.2

Tags: meteor

I get this error after updating meteor from 0.8 to 0.9.2

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function dynamic_template.js:371
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined helpers.js:139
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function router.js:61
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RouteController' of undefined iron-router-progress.js?2b52a697e5a2fba4ec827721c08cfdd0a5bae508:25
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RouteController' of undefined fast-render.js?b28103b086a46881dd8dde215dd8dfe85b2f693b:27
Uncaught Error: There are multiple templates named '__IronDefaultLayout__'. Each template needs a unique name. templating.js:9
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function router.js:61
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'IronRouterProgress' of undefined global-imports.js?e50dcd2c89bf87a5ac45632b7280655943c6b817:6
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.admin_dashboard.js?00ebfb68d4f1c5e5ae7f687b10f53b2947bc5bb8:2
```

Comment: Meteor 0.9.2 needs iron:router@1.0.0-pre1 to work properly, have you upgraded iron:router accordingly ?

Comment: I *think* that's the other way around. pre-1 needs 0.9.2, but 0.9.2 can run with IR 0.9.3.

Comment: @KelvinMartinLigue Have you gotten this to work?